# Django FormWizard Dynamically Alter form_list

Tags: django, django-formwizard

I'm having some issues with the form wizard, that maybe someone can shed some light on.  According docstring in the method process_step: I can "dynamically alter self.form_list".  So, based on my project needs, I'm appending forms to the form_list.  The forms I'm appending contain questions and answers: http://dpaste.com/hold/152201/

The issue is that when 2 people hit the formwizard at the same time, they start to see each others questions and answers.  I guess I don't understand how process_step suggests I can dynamically alter the form_list, when by doing so I'm modifying the form list of another user.
 Is the form_list a shared object among visitors hitting the formwizard url defined in urls.py? I've seen this issue under apache2/prefork/worker/mod_wsgi, and while running the app with runserver.

Comment: almost smells like session collisions

Comment: The more I read about the issues behind dynamic/concurrent form sessions, the more I think, for good or bad, it's a formwizard issue.

Answer (score 2):

How do you use FormWizard? If you're putting it in urls.py like docs says then it could be cached, i had that issue couple of times. Just put it in a view like:

```
def my_view(request):
    return FormWizard(request)
```

UPDATE: Example from real

```
def registration_wizard(request, template_name=None):
    rw = RegistrationWizard([RegistrationForm, 0])
    #hack formwizard to replace default template
    if template_name:
        rw.get_template = lambda x: template_name

    return rw(request)
```

here RegistrationWizard is a FormWizard subclass with dynamic form_list, [RegistrationForm, 0] is needed because if there's only one form at creation time, wizard won't get to form_list function. Template thing is pretty self-explanatory

Comment: Thanks for the response Dmitry.  I am placing my FormWizard in urls.py.  Do you have a working example of placing the FormWizard in a view?  I did get your suggestion working by following the example provided at http://www.djangosnippets.org/snippets/1833/, but my problem seems to persist.

Comment: I'm doing my best to work through my issue.  I like your suggestion (I like defining the Wizard in a view instead of urls.py), however I'm still having issues.  I need to do some debugging to make sure it's not something I'm screwing up.  I'll keep you updated, and hopefully put a big green checkmark next to your answer.

Comment: Just to followup with this post, I ditched trying to dynamically insert forms into the form_list.  There were some architectural decisions made in the last few days that made the FormWizard approach for this part of the app not necessary anyway.

Comment: Also, Dimitry, based on what I was trying to accomplish, your suggestion didn't solve the issue I was having. I needed the "statefulness" of the cached form_list, but the form_list independence of the view approach.  No matter what angle I attempted to approach my problem from, nothing seemed to work.  Thanks for your help though.

Comment: well i think you just need your own implementation :) formwizard in django's core looks like abandoned project really