# Can a step be repeated in Django 1.6 form wizard?

Tags: django, formwizard

Can a step be repeated in the Django form wizard? I'd like to repeat a step an indefinite number of times depending on the needs of the user.

Comment: Similar question for Django 1.4: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13052224/how-to-dynamically-repeat-steps-in-django-formwizard-1-4

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/ref/contrib/formtools/form-wizard/) for the form wizard has directions on how to make conditional steps. I used that along with a function factory to make a few hundred conditional steps, so essentially the user can repeat the last step as many times as they want.

```
from django.contrib.formtools.wizard.views import SessionWizardView
from myapp.forms import BasicInformation, MoreInformation


def function_factory(cond_step):

    def info(wizard):
        cleaned_data = wizard.get_cleaned_data_for_step(str(cond_step)) or {}
        return cleaned_data.get("add_another_step", False)

    return info


def make_condition_stuff(extra, cond_step):
    cond_funcs = {}
    cond_dict = {}
    form_lst = [
        BasicInformation,
        MoreInformation,
    ]

    for x in range(extra):
        key1 = "info{0}".format(x)
        cond_funcs[key1] = function_factory(cond_step)
        cond_dict[str(cond_step+1)] = cond_funcs[key1]
        form_lst.append(MoreInformation)

    return cond_funcs, cond_dict, form_lst


last_step_before_extras = 1
extra_steps = 300

cond_funcs, cond_dict, form_list = make_condition_stuff(
    extra_steps,
    last_step_before_extras
)


class InfoWizard(SessionWizardView):
    form_list = form_list
    condition_dict = cond_dict
    ...
```